# SQL query with multiple "IN" on same many-to-many table

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I've got m2m relationship like this:

```
#main table
CREATE TABLE products_product (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    company_id integer,
    user_id integer,
    type_id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    description character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    tags character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    image character varying(200) NOT NULL
);
#intermediate table
CREATE TABLE products_ingridientbound (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ingridient_id integer NOT NULL,
    company_id integer NOT NULL,
    price double precision NOT NULL,
    active boolean NOT NULL,
    "asTopping" boolean NOT NULL
);
#final m2m table
CREATE TABLE products_ingridientproductbound (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    ingridient_id integer NOT NULL,
    "optionValue" integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "products_ingridientproductbound_optionValue_check" CHECK (("optionValue" >= 0))
);
```

All I want to do is to get products, which has 2 (in this example) ingridient groups, one with ID in range (16, 17, 18, 19), and another in range (43, 44, 45). I want ingridient ID to be in both groups simultaneously.

My query looks like this (it's actually generated by django orm):

```
SELECT "products_product"."id","products_product"."name",
FROM "products_product"
INNER JOIN "products_ingridientproductbound" 
ON ("products_product"."id" = "products_ingridientproductbound"."product_id")
WHERE ("products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (16, 17, 18, 19)
AND "products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (43, 44, 45)) LIMIT 21
```

It gives me 0 results, but if I run query with only one group of IN queries than it works!

Here is data in my "products_ingridientproductbound" table. I thought that my query could return product 3, as it is in both groups (16 and 45), but now I'm confused a bit.
[Screenshot of phpPgAdmin](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/9900/pgtable.jpg)

Comment: From a quick search on google it seams that postgres does support the intersect operator.  See my answer.

Comment: The nicest thing you could do for the developer that maintains this when you are gone (and to make you look more professional to your boss) - spell "ingredient" correctly in the database. It is a little thing, but it is really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are after, doing an INNER JOIN is not what you are looking for here, I would use a [subquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/functions-subquery.html) instead.

You want the product id and name that have both ingredients, correct?

I didn't test this statement but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT "products_product"."id","products_product"."name",
FROM "products_product"
WHERE (
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "products_ingridientproductbound" WHERE "products_product"."id" = "products_ingridientproductbound"."product_id" AND "products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (16, 17, 18, 19))
        AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "products_ingridientproductbound" WHERE "products_product"."id" = "products_ingridientproductbound"."product_id" AND "products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (43, 44, 45))
)
LIMIT 21
```

Edit: remove silly remark about combining, thanks jvanderh.

Comment: The reason he can't combine is that he needs products that are in both, if he combines them, he will get all of the products that have one of those IDs

Comment: It not just works, it's just what I need! :) This way I may create more EXISTS statements and pass em to Django ORM. Another question here is performace...

Answer (score 1):

You ask in your two IN clauses that the same field is in two sets without common elements. Therefore you will always get a false in one of the clauses, hence your AND will be false.

Answer (score 1):

txwikinger is right. If you want to filter product that have two related ingridientbounds you need to have two JOINs in the query like this:

```
SELECT "products_product"."id","products_product"."name",
FROM "products_product"
INNER JOIN "products_ingridientproductbound" ig1
ON ("products_product"."id" = ig1."product_id")
INNER JOIN "products_ingridientproductbound" ig2
ON ("products_product"."id" = ig2."product_id")
WHERE (ig1."ingridient_id" IN (16, 17, 18, 19)
AND ig2."ingridient_id" IN (43, 44, 45)) 
LIMIT 21
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use INTERSECT like this

```
SELECT "products_product"."id","products_product"."name",
FROM "products_product"
INNER JOIN "products_ingridientproductbound" 
ON ("products_product"."id" = "products_ingridientproductbound"."product_id")
WHERE ("products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (16, 17, 18, 19)

INTERSECT 

SELECT "products_product"."id","products_product"."name",
FROM "products_product"
INNER JOIN "products_ingridientproductbound" 
ON ("products_product"."id" = "products_ingridientproductbound"."product_id")
WHERE ("products_ingridientproductbound"."ingridient_id" IN (43, 44, 45)
```

Meaning return rows that are in both queries.  Check if your DB has that option.